# Ordered insertion in linkedHashSet, any performant way ?

Tags: java, performance, data-structures, linkedhashset

So I have a LinkedHashSet , with values  say   a1, a2, , b, c1, c2

I want to replace,   b  with  x , such that the order of x should be same as order of b.

One obvious way would be

```
 private LinkedHashSet<String> orderedSubstitution(final Set<String> originalOrderedSet, final String oldItem,
            final String newItem) {
        final LinkedHashSet<String> newOrderedSet = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
        // Things we do to maintain order in a linkedHashSet
        for (final String stringItem : originalOrderedSet) {
            if (stringItem.equals(oldItem)) {
                newOrderedSet.add(newItem);
            } else {
                newOrderedSet.add(stringItem);
            }
        }
        return newOrderedSet;
    }
```

not only this is O(n) i also *feel* this is not the fastest way.  Any better solution ?
NOTE : I HAVE TO use linkedHashMap.

Comment: Since we follow the 'final' , just wondering why you think it is clutter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a structure Map
2. Insert all the string with  < String, OrderOfTheString>
3. Do the insertion of the new String by adding a small Delta after the current string's OrderOfTheString.
4. Convert Map to LikedHashSet

I know it is complicated but it is definately better when we have linked hash Map of ~1000000 elements and there are about 1000 elements to be inserted.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to use a subclass of LinkedHashSet that has the replacement built in, e.g.:

```
public class ReplacingLinkedHashSet extends LinkedHashSet<String> {
    private final String what;
    private final String with;

    public ReplacingLinkedHashSet(String what, String with) {
        this.what = what;
        this.with = with;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<String> iterator() {
        final Iterator<String> iterator = super.iterator();
        return new Iterator<String>() {
            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return iterator.hasNext();
            }

            @Override
            public String next() {
                String next = iterator.next();
                return what.equals(next) ? with : next;
            }

            @Override
            public void remove() {
                iterator.remove();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

But that means the replacement would have to be known before you fill the Set.
(Of course you could easily turn this `<String>` version into a generic one.

---

Responding to comments:

OK, then there is no way to solve it without a full iteration. You could however just leave the LinkedHashSet untouched and decorate the iterator when retrieving the values.

Comment: As you mentioned that is the problem !  We dont know what will be substituted and when it will be substituted.