# Replace the value of an item on LinkedHashSet

Tags: java, linkedhashset

I have a `LinkedHashSet` that stores `Json` Objects, I'm using it to keep the order of the insertion of the items. However now, I would like depending on a condition to update the value of a specific item.

To remove a specific item is quite easy, but I didn't figure out how to do the update.

```
LinkedHashSet<JsonObject> mediaList = new LinkedHashSet<JsonObject>;

......

int i = 0;
int tagPosition = 5;
JsonObject mediaItem = null;
final Iterator<JsonObject> iterator = mediaList.iterator ();

while (iterator.hasNext ()) {
    if (i == tagPosition) {
        mediaItem = iterator.next ();
        mediaItem.set ("type", "New Value"); //the new value putted on the JsonObject of the specif location

        // Here, how to update the Set ??

        break;
    }
    iterator.next ();
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Set doesn't allow search nor update of its elements. You should remove the element or use another structure.

Comment: Thank you. Is there Another structure that keeps the order of insertion and allow the update ?

Comment: [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) might be an option. As long as you use the same key, you can update a value without affecting the iteration order.

Comment: AFAIK you could use `LinkedHashMap<JsonObject, JsonObject>` which means your key is your value as well, then retrieve it by the `key` and update the value accordingly.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Would that mean you need to keep the original key? If you use the value as the key then updating the value would mean that your key would differ, which would place it at the end of the map...

Comment: @user3580294 as long as the `hashCode` remains the same, there's nothing to worry about.

Comment: I'm afraid that storing two `JsonObject` as `key/value` will affect performances... If it's so, I will look to generate some unique `primitive` IDs as keys..

Comment: You know, any `Set` uses a `Map` behind the scenes, so instead of *getting worse performance* you're saving it.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza That's true... Wouldn't it be likely that an update to a `JSONObject` would change the hashcode though? I'm pretty sure that at least for Google's implementation of JSON the hashcode depends on the contents of the object.

Comment: @user3580294 that will depend on the `hashCode` implementation of `JsonObject`. I don't know from which library is and if is immutable as well (which I hope).

Comment: ... wondering why a variable that is called "media **List** " is implemented as a set, and whether the issue could not be solved by just letting mediaList be a `List`...

Comment: @Marco13 Well... I used media`List` to refer to what does the `Set` refers literraly : `a list of medias`, and I used the `Set` maybe because a set cannot contain `doublons` and maybe a `LinkedHashSet` to maintain the order of insertion...

Comment: Sure, but depending on which operations you want to perform, you might consider a different data structure. In any case, when you change an object that is contained in a LinkedHashSet in *any* way that affects the `equals` or `hashCode` implementation, this will cause inconsistencies. How many elements does this set contain? If it's less than 10000 or so, I would not hesitate doing the checks for duplicates manually on insertion, but again: That depends.

Comment: Related: [Ordered insertion in linkedHashSet, any performant way ?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12826916)